# Make absolute div take 100% height of parent

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a div whose size depends on its content.
I want to have an absolute child which takes the whole space.

In Firefox I get the wanted result but not in Chromium.
How to fix it?

Which browser is rendering against the specification?

```html
<div style="position:relative;float:left;">
    <div style="position:absolute;display:table;left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:red;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">TEST</div>
    </div>

    <!-- this is an img in real with unknown size -->
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: display:table is the culprit, remove it and use another way to center your element (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218694/8620333)

Comment: But why remove it? It should be valid.

Comment: you are using is to center your element and it's not the best way to do it, it's more a hacky way and as you noticed it doesn't work properly in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `display` of this div to `display:flex` and use `margin: auto` to center the text:

```html
<div style="position:relative;float:left">
    <div style="position:absolute;display:flex;left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:red;">
        <div style="margin: auto">TEST</div>
    </div>

    <!-- this is an img in real with unknown size -->
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Or with `display: flex` and `align-items: center`:

```html
<div style="position:relative;float:left">
    <div style="position:absolute;display:flex;left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:red;align-items: center">
        <div>TEST</div>
    </div>

    <!-- this is an img in real with unknown size -->
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is no longer centered vertically.